# Information about state.x77 dataset in R

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R. I tried to apply aggregate function to state.x77 dataset.

```
aggregate(state.x77,list(Region=state.region),mean)

aggregate(state.x77,list(Region=state.region,Cold=state.x77[,"Frost"]>130),mean)
```

I fail to see what the function does to the dataset since I don't know much information about the dataset. I have applied `str()` and `summary()` functions but to no avail. Please do someone shed light on it.

Comment: In the first case, you are grouping by 'state.region' and getting the `mean` of each column of 'state.x77` which is not right because it will get the mean of character/factor columns resulting in extra NA columns.  In the second case, the same thing is done using two grouping variables, where the second one is a logical one.

Comment: @RHertel The `datasets::state.x77` and simply `state.x77` is working for me, but `data(state.x77)` results in warning. @VenugopalBukkala Then you are using different datasets ('state.region') being a vector and the state.x77 with only numeric values.  You get the group by mean of each of the columns based on the 'state.region'.  In the second case, you are also creating a logical vector as grouping variable as mentioned in the comment above.

Comment: I think that `data(state)` would work. There are several objects belonging to that dataset, each separated with a dot. See `?state`

Comment: @RHertel Yes, it works.  I guess that might be the reason.

Comment: Thank You akrun and RHertel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get information about `state.x77` tpye `?state.x77` into your console.

Comment: Exellent Answer!!!